# Flask with SQLAlchemy persisting large form (newbie)

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I'm writing a lot of boilerplate like code to try and persist my form data. In other languages I've not had to manually map the form attribute to the model prior to saving I'm wondering does python/flask has a similar approach? I'd ideally prefer to manually map all my form fields to simply persist a db record.

[edit]
To be clear this approach works fine for me the records are persisted properly however it seems kind of inefficient. In another piece of code I was able to use the wtf library `{{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}`
to create a form an html form  without explicitly listing all its fields. Given I have the same names for my model attributes as I do for the form attributes I was wondering if I can do the same?
[edit]

Any feedback

Example below..

I have a largish model "product"

```
class Product(db.Model):
    field1 = db.Column(db.String(200))
    field2 = db.Column(db.String(200))
    ....
    field30 = db.Column(db.String(200))
```

It's represented as a flask form e.g.

```
class ProductForm(FlaskForm):
   field1 = StringField('Field 1', validators=[DataRequired()])
   field2 = TextAreaField('Field 2 Label')
   field30 = TextAreaField('Field 30 Label')
   submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

Here I try and map and persist the product record...

```
def save_product(self, product, form):
    product.field1 = form.field.data
    #lots more tedious form to model mapping
    db.session.add(product)
    # commit the data to the database
    db.session.commit()
```

In my routes.py I have the following. I see it being called and the record does indeed persist.

```
def crud():
    form = CrudForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        product = Product()
        product.save_product(product, form, new=True)
        flash(_('Product Saved'))
        return redirect(url_for('main.index'))

    return render_template('crud.html', title=_('Product CRUD'),
                           form=form)
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Need more details about your code. Where is save_product method and where do you use it? I don't see any Product() init

Comment: no error @yoursweater just wondering if it can be down without explicitly mapping form to model.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the names of your form fields are the same as the names of your database columns it is possible to cut down on the boilerplate. A dict of all of the fields in your form is accessible as the form.data property and this can be passed directly through as keyword arguments when your create the new instance of your model rather than setting them one at a time afterwards.

```
product = Product(**form.data)
```